# Drawing a cube using Indexed Draw in modern OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glfw, glew

I'm trying to draw a cube using indexed draw in OpenGL 3.3. But it does not show up right...
Here is what I tried doing.

```
GLfloat vertices01[] = {
  -1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
  -1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
  1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
  1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,
  -1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
  -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
  1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f,
  1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f
};
unsigned int indices01[] = {
  0, 2, 3, 1,
  2, 6, 7, 3,
  6, 4, 5, 7,
  4, 0, 1, 5,
  0, 4, 6, 2,
  1, 5, 7, 3
};


Mesh* obj3 = new Mesh();
obj3->CreateMesh(vertices01, indices01, 24, 24);
meshList.push_back(obj3);

meshList[0]->RenderMesh();
```

//in mesh class
    indexCount = numOfIndices;

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices[0])*numOfIndices, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices[0])*numOfVertices, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindVertexArray(VAO);

//bind ibo
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

the output shows a partial cube whose each side had one triangle each and also a triangle going through it's diagonal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a compatibility profile context, then you can keep your indices an use [`GL_QUADS`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Quads) instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`. But that's deprecated ([Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) ).

Since the primitive type is `GL_TRIANGLES`, each side of the cube has to be formed by 2 triangles. See [Triangle primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives).

Change the index buffer to solve the issue:

```cpp
unsigned int indices01[] = {
  0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1,
  2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 3,
  6, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7,
  4, 0, 1, 4, 1, 5,
  0, 4, 6, 0, 6, 2,
  1, 5, 7, 1, 7, 3,
};
```

An alternative solution would be to use the primitive type [`GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) and a [Primitive Restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) index.

Enable primitive restart and define a restart index:

e.g.

```cpp
glEnable( GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART );
glPrimitiveRestartIndex( 99 );
```

Define 2 triangle strips, which are separated by the restart index:

```cpp
unsigned int indices01[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5,
    99, // 99 is the restart index
    7, 3, 5, 1, 4, 0, 6, 2
};
int indexCOunt = 17;
```

And draw the elements:

```cpp
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

---

Note, the [Index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) binding is stored in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object).
So it is sufficient to bind the index buffer once, when the VAO is setup:

```cpp
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);  

// [...]

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);

// [...]

// glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); <---- delete this

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Then it is superfluous to bind the index buffer again, before the draw call:

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO); <---- now this is superfluous 

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```